# What's the right way to use Ejabberd in a social network App?

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I'm working on a project where we need to implement a chat system with a (kinda) social network. and We opted to use Ejabberd ( any other suggestions ? ).

- How can we prevent third party xmpp clients from connecting to the server ?
- When it comes to permissions of who can message who, do we need to create our custom Ejabberd module ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can we prevent third party xmpp clients from connecting to the server ?

Some ideas:

- Filter connections from IP Address, if they should come only from a small range that you already know. See `ip` ACL in https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/basic/#acl-definition
- Modify an existing auth mechanism in ejabberd in a way that only your client knows how to get accepted by ejabberd. Of course, somebody could reverse-engineer your secret method and write an alternative client.

> When it comes to permissions of who can message who, do we need to create our custom Ejabberd module ?

Some ideas, maybe you can adapt your requirements to use one of them:

- mod_isolation: acts at the vhost level https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/tree/master/mod_isolation
- mod_filter: acts at the ACL level. https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/tree/master/mod_filter
- And probably the best one: set [mod_roster](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/modules/#mod-roster)->access to not allow users modifying their rosters. Then set [mod_block_strangers](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/modules/#mod-block-strangers) to only allow people communicate with people in their rosters. And finally populate the rosters with the desired contacts (for that you can use [push_roster_all](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/#push-roster-all) or whatever command that make your live easier)